# Wikipedia API - displaying only 4 results

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia-api

I'm using the Wikipedia API to display some articles. The only issue is that it only displays the first 4 results. I've looked at similar questions but still can't find a way to display more. [Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f5ukxj0/4/).

JS:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {

        if(e.which == 13) { 

           var searchTerm = $('#searchy').val();
           var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchTerm + "&format=json&callback=?";

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    //console.log(data[1][0]);
                    //console.log(data[2][0]);
                    //console.log(data[3][0]);
                    $('#output').html('');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#output').prepend("<li><a href=" + data[3][0] + ">" +  data[1][0] + "</a><p>" + data[2][0] + "</p></li>");

                    $('#centbox').css("top", "14%");
                    $('#resultati').css("top", "16%");
                }
            },
                error: function(errorMessage){
                alert("Error!");
            }

            })

        };
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

But `data.length` is ***always*** going to be 4: `[0]` is the search, `[1]` is an array of article names, `[2]` is an array of summaries, and `[3]` is an array of links.

So perhaps:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
    $('#output').prepend("<li><a href=" + data[3][i] + ">" +  data[1][i] + "</a><p>" + data[2][i] + "</p></li>");
```

Comment: Also you might want to learn that the default limit is 10, you can add a query in the URL `limit=N` to change the max number of results.